# How to describe the partition given for the given equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, equivalence-relations, set-partition

Given the equivalence relation below, describe the partition?

Equivalence relation: $$R=\{(a,a),(b,b), (c,c), (d,d), (e,e), (a,b), (b,a), (a,d), (d,a), (b,d), (d,b)\}$$ on $S=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$.

I'm not sure what exactly the question is asking or how to format the answer. So far, I think the partition depends on if the pair has the same two elements or if the pair contains an $a$,$b$ or $d$. Thanks

Comment: What is the definition you have that relates equivalence relations on $S$ and equivalence classes/partitions of $S$?

Answer (score 2):

We know that any equivalence relation gives a rise to a partition of the set. The partition is given in such a manner that $a$ and $b$ are in the same subset iff $a\sim b$. Hence from the relation we can conclude that the partition is:

$$S_1 = \{a,b,d\} \quad S_2 = \{c\} \quad S_3 = \{e\}$$

Answer (score 0):

A relation is (by definition) fully defined by its graph.
So, here the subset R of SxS. 
As you may know S/R, the collection of all of the equivalence classes, is a partition of S.
So, what are the equivalence classes?
Well, we have:
[a] = {a, b, d}.
Hence, [a]=[b]=[d].
For c, we have:
[c] = {c},
and for e:
[e] = {e}.
So, the partition of S associated with R is S/R = {{a, b, d}, {c}, {e}}.